# Find inf and sup of a set with a pair of elements

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Find the infimum and supremum of the set D given by

$$D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{ZxZ}|x^2+y^2≤9\}$$

I suspect the supremum to be $9$ and the infimum to be $0$. But how do I prove it?

Comment: Would you please tell us what is the supremum and the infimum of a subset of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It's a cartesian product. We have $\mathbb{ZxZ}=\{(z,z)|z\in\mathbb{Z},z \in\mathbb{Z}\}$ so it's an Archimedian order that has neither upper or lower bound. That's how I understand it anyway

Comment: When I finished reading your answer, I didn't know more than when I started, except for one thing: you don't know what a Cartesian product is.

Comment: You need to describe the order relation to be used for the question to make sense. We can hazard and guess that may be a lexicographic ordering was intended, but it is your job to describe it precisely, because there are different ordering leading to different answers. Doing that may actually help you answer your question.

Comment: And, like José, I'm not sure you understand what a Cartesian product is. At least you have trouble dealing with the set builder notation. Hint: when you write $(z,z)$ the two occurences of $z$ must be the same occurence. So the set you described only contains points $(0,0), (1,1), (-1,-1)$ etc. It does not contain the points like $(1,2), (4,-3)$ where the coordinates are not the same. Your difficulties with the set builder notation may actually be at the heart of your problems. I strongly suggest that you go talk with your teacher. They can explain these things to you, but it takes time.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see that. I should have written, forexample $\{(x,y)|x\in \mathbb{Z},y\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. I think you hit the nail on the head with the notation issue and a more general lack of knowledge, because I think what throws me off is how to handle pairs instead of a single variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would order a set of points but I'll try to help.

The expression defining the set ($x^2+y^2\leq 9$) might look familiar. And in fact it is the Pythagorean Theorem. This means that the set can be thought as a set of right angle triangles whose hypotenuse is less than or equal to $\sqrt{9}=3$. Equivalently you can think it as the lattice points* inside a circle of radius 3.

Eitherway, you're now able to construct the set yourself. Here is the set but only including the points from the first quadrant. To get the others, you just have to add negative sign in front of the coordinates.

$$\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(3,0)\}$$

For example, if you choose to order the points accroding to the sum of the coordinates, we see that the point $(2,2)$ has the greates sum, 4. In this case the point $(2,2)$ is the maximum and $(-2,-2)$ the minimum. Since the set is finite, the minimum and maximum are infimum and supremum respecticely.

* Lattice points are the points with integer coordinates.